# How to change file name in shell?

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I want to change file name using shell script.

Origin file names are `aa.docs_YYYYMMDDhhmmss`, `bb.pdf_YYYYMMDDhhmmss`, `cc.xxx_YYYYMMDDhhmmss` and more. `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` is unique at this time.

Destination file names are in Oracle DB Table and will be `xxx.docs_YYYYMMDDhhmmss`.

Those have same `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`.

How to change file name from DB using shell script?

Comment: This is not a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the link between source file names and destination file names?

Comment: YYYYMMDDhhmmss is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.You should use proper value for `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` as per your source files.

```
for file_name in *_YYYYMMDDhhmmss
do
   file_type=`echo $file_name | cut -f2 -d '.' | cut -f1 -d '_'`
   file_date=`echo $file_name | cut -f2 -d '.' | cut -f2 -d '_'`

 db_filename=`sqlplus -s user/pwd <<INP
 set heading off
 set pagesize 0
 select file_name from yourtable where file_name like '%${file_type}%${file_date}';
 INP`

    mv ${file_name} ${db_filename}
done
```